# nginx extending a rewrite rule with a condition

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have the following rewrite rule, used for WordPress Network to handle the file requests:

```
   location @rewrite {                                                     
            rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;                        
            rewrite ^.*/files/(.*)$ /wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 last; 
    }
```

I seems that running owncloud 3 on the same domain the dav requests are caught by this rule. Therefore I'd like to extend the line to only be applied of no `owncloud` word was found in the uri.

Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can write a more specific rule, then that's probably beneficial - you don't want to accidentally exempt locations that should be rewritten; is there a specific directory you can apply this to?

That said, you can definitely just exempt anything with `owncloud`; add this to the `location` block above the existing rewrite lines:

```
rewrite ^(.*owncloud.*)$ $1 last;
```